# mysql count(*) with group by get one by one , not the total sum

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

The main idea is this:

```
id  name  count_n
1   'a'   3
2   'a'   3
3   'a'   3
4   'b'   2
5   'b'   2
```

I want to get the `count_n` like this:

```
id  name  count_n
1   'a'   1
2   'a'   2
3   'a'   3
4   'b'   1
5   'b'   2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables for this:

```
SELECT id, name,
       @seq := IF(@n = name, @seq+1,
                  IF(@n := name, 1, 1)) AS count_n
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @n := '') AS v
ORDER BY id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa94b/1)